# SQL Server Profiler implementation using C#/VB.NET

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005

I wish to implement [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) in a C#/[VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) application. Is there a good example of how to do this?

I have searched on Google, but I didn't find a good working example. I don't have SQL Server Profiler on my system and also don't have [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) (it is on a different system).

How do I create a profiler for my self?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the blog post *[Programmatically receiving profiler events (in real time) from SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/26/Receiving-Profiler-Events.aspx)*.

Comment: yes but I don't know how to create the trace definition file , as i don't have the sql server profiler on my system, Although I have Sql server management studio but don't have profiler in it, I am using AnjLab Sql Profiler on my system (not the profiler which is integrated with sql server management studio.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of Profiler on a different machine. Make a trace that you like, then script it using the File menu. Then take that script to your main machine to create your server-side trace.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, But the problem is that I don't have sql server Profile, And can't get it from any where, is there any way to do it without sql server profiler ?????
thanks again